# Consuming rest api timeout

Tags: c#, rest

How to deal with timeout problem when calling REST service.
My GetAsync function:

```
    private async Task<string> GetAsync(string endPoint, string id)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            SevenMResultNx<string> result = new SevenMResultNx<string>(false);

            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(token);

            // HTTP GET
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(String.Format("{0}/{1}", endPoint, id));
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                return response.ReasonPhrase;
            }
        }
    }
```

is called like:

```
        Task<string> task = GetAsync(endPoint, id);
        var responseGet = task.Result;
```

Whenever endpoint is unavaiable, I got problem because process waits infinity.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest making your method accept a `CancellationToken` that you can then pass onto the `GetAsync` and `ReadAsStringAsync` methods.

You can easily create a cancellation token which will expire after a certain time:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
var text = await GetAsync(endpoint, id, cts.Token);
```

In addition, using `Result` in the caller is almost certainly a mistake. It means if you're using a scheduler that has a single thread, you'll deadlock - your thread will be waiting for the task to complete, but it won't be able to complete because when the `httpClient.GetAsync` call completes, it needs to execute more code in the same thread. Two improvements:

- In your `GetAsync` method, where you're awaiting tasks, use `ConfigureAwait(false)` as you probably don't care which thread the rest of the async method continues on
- Make the *calling* code asynchronous as well, and await the returned task.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Maybe there is an error in the way I call task.

Comment: @iljon: Well you shouldn't be using `task.Result` like that - I hadn't spotted that. You should be using `await`, in almost all cases. But we can't tell whether or not you passed the `CancellationToken` on appropriately - I've amended my answer slightly as I hadn't seen the `ReadAsStringAsync` call. I'll edit the answer to include using await as well.